# Round nullable decimal to 5 decimal places

Tags: .net

```
vol = Decimal.Round(exposure.Volatility, 5);
```

This won't let me round

```
exposure.Volatility
```

to a decimal b/c it say's conversion from decimal? to decimal cannot take place.

How do I round that number to 5 decimal places? It's a nullable decimal.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assuming a null value is equal to zero in this circumstance, something like:

```
vol = exposure.Volatility.HasValue ? Decimal.Round(exposure.Volatility.Value, 5) : 0;
```

If "vol" is also nullable then do:

```
vol = exposure.Volatility.HasValue ? Decimal.Round(exposure.Volatility.Value, 5) : null;
```

Comment: After getting bitten by that a few times, I figured it's probably a good idea. :)

Answer (score 6):

Use the `Nullable`'s `Value` property:

```
vol = Decimal.Round(exposure.Volatility.Value, 5);
```

Comment: This will throw `InvalidOperationException` if the variable does not have a value.

Answer (score 0):

```
vol = Decimal.Round(exposure.Volatility.Value, 5);
```

Comment: This will throw `InvalidOperationException` if the variable does not have a value.

Comment: Yes it will. I assume if your using nullable types you are checking the .HasValue property somewhere before you call the .Value property.